# How to bind a single element from a model object in angular in a template

Tags: json, angular

Can someone give me a clue, how to bind a variable value from a .model created?

I have used ng for in a div, then I can interpolate values from a .model.ts using:

```
ngFor let list of lists

then i {{name.list}}
```

But in other div, I just can show a dynamic name of a .model.ts, like name.list.

How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Please try to add a block of your HTML and TS coding and a little more clear explanation.

Comment: You have an example in the [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel#using-ngmodel-on-a-standalone-control)

Comment: Hi @adrisons . imagine a people login on the web site, then with his name id, I would like to set his name fixed in the template like "Hello ID". If another person log into, the name will change based on his id value. I just want to figure out a better aproach to do this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have in your component some data like:

```js
  usersList = [
    { name: "Michael", id: 1 },
    { name: "Linda", id: 2 }
  ];
```

In your template html you should do something like this:

```html
<h2>List of users</h2>
<ul *ngIf="userList.length">
  <li *ngFor="let user of userList">
    Hello {{user.name}} (id: {{user.id}})
  </li>
</ul>
<div *ngIf="!userList.length">No users</div>
```

Comment: Thank you adrisons. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: You're welcome. You should accept the answer then.